# path activiti: Manage->Deployments->Upload

Tags: activiti

Acitivti: Deploy the claim management process BAR archive, located on the Activiti project under the "deployments" folder (file claimAnalysis.bar), going to Manage->Deployments->Upload new on the Activiti explorer. Observe that if you change the Activiti process, you'll need to generate again the deployment BAR file by right clicking on the Activiti project on the package explorer of eclipse and selecting "Create deployment artifacts".

We try to dockerize our activiti platform and our apps.
Where will the BAR file be stored on my tomcat server? We don't want a manual upload.

Answer (score 2):

The "bar" file will not be stored on the filesystem, rather, on import/upload it is parsed and saved to the runtime server repository (database).

If you want to "dockerize" your installation and have process applications automatically deployed, then place the bar file in the resources folder of your webapp and use the demoDataGenerator technique to auto deploy.

Comment: Thanks, we are using a .jar inside /webapps/activiti-explorer/WEB-INF/lib (is this our webapp?) + can you maybe give a URL about that technique?

Comment: Your engine.properties will include the following line:
create.demo.definitions=true
If this is true, then any process file found in /webapps/activiti-explorer/WEB-INF/classes/org/activiti/explorer/demo/process will automatically be deployed on startup. The startup bean that handles this is DemoDataConfiguration.java